kWh/kWp Solar atlas meaning
I have a doubt, if I read the value of 'Specific photovoltaic power output' from pages like this solar atlas what does this relationship means? if I have 1 kWp installed capacity I will generate 3.958 kWh on a day or does it means that at peak conditions I am generating 3.958 kWh on a day?
If the meaning is the first, and it means that for each kWp I would generate 4 kWh, does I have to multiply this value for the panel efficiency? or is the average value for commercial panels with typical efficiencies included?
can I use this relationship for a raw calculation of a project on a specific location? for example If I install 100 kWp I will daily generate 400 kWh?
Please forgive me if this is a kind of stupid question, I have searched over many sources and have just got ambiguous, source less information.


The solar panel efficiency is already included in the 1kWp figure. A lower efficiency panel would have to be physically larger to provide that 1kWp.
The calculation you are doing is correct.

thank you very much, do you maybe have a source? I need to to show to my college

@user14398375 - Please see the edits.
